# Why "LC_ALL=C" cannot speed up "bzgrep"

Tags: grep

In terms of the cases that covers ASCII only, we could use `LC_ALL=C` to significantly speed up the `grep` procedure. 
Since `bzgrep` is a lot similar to `grep`, I tried to adopt this as well. Turns out it didn't help much.
The command lines I used are listed as following:

```
$ time bzgrep Debug 001.log.bz2 | sed -n '/^09:00/ , /^09:30/p' | grep "Pattern1.*Pattern2" > /dev/null
$ time LC_ALL=C bzgrep Debug 001.log.bz2 | sed -n '/^09:00/ , /^09:30/p' | grep "Pattern1.*Pattern2" > /dev/null
```

Update:

```
$ time bzgrep

real    1m51.686s
user    1m52.310s
sys     0m6.682s

$ time LC_ALL=C bzgrep
real    1m51.835s
user    1m52.455s
sys     0m6.738s

$ time grep

real    1m9.553s
user    1m3.189s
sys     0m2.120s

$ time LC_ALL grep

real    0m4.136s
user    0m3.187s
sys     0m0.946s
```

Comment: bzip a single file. Compare `grep`, `LC_ALL=C grep`, `bzgrep`, and `LC_ALL=C bzgrep`. What are the times?

Comment: @Ryan♦ `LC_ALL=C grep` is much faster than `grep`, while `LC_ALL=C bzgrep` and `bzgrep` are almost the same. And this difference is exactly what I'm confused about.

Comment: What are the actual numbers?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've updated the original post,  cannot see how that helps though:-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bzgrep isn't ignoring LC_ALL entirely, you're probably seeing a performance bottleneck in which the decompression performance limits the speed at which the actual grep code gets the data in the first place, thus making the speed of the actual grep code largely moot.

To use a car analogy, imagine that you have two groups of car washers—one that can wash a car in a minute, and another that takes five minutes.  You have ten cars to wash.  The first team washes ten cars in ten minutes; the other team washes ten cars in 50 minutes.

Now suppose that you have a fire marshall who doesn't like having that many cars on the property at once and decides to solve the problem by allowing exactly one car to enter the car wash, precisely at the top of every hour.  Thus, each team finishes with its car and then waits either 55 or 59 minutes for the next one.

In that scenario, the first team gets a car and washes it in a minute, waits an hour, washes another car, etc.  They start washing the tenth car nine hours after they started washing the first, so it takes nine hours and one minute in total.  The second team does the same thing, but takes five minutes to wash the last car, so it takes then nine hours and five minutes in total.

In much the same way, if the grep part is dramatically faster than the decompression part, then assuming you have a multicore CPU, the total time depends only upon the time required to decompress the data plus the time to grep the very last chunk of data.

Comment: This makes sense. Any idea we can speed up `bzgrep` (or other alternative methods instead of `bzgrep` to read from an compressed file)?

Comment: pbzip2 | grep, maybe, assuming the overhead of the pipe doesn't kill any performance win from the parallelization.